# Location of event components in a multi class situation

Tags: c#, class, events, delegates

I am trying to understand how events should be properly constructed when you have more than one class. For instance if you have class that detects value and you want to update a text box in a form, where should the event components be placed. From what I read:

Event component - [Location]
1. Delegate - [Globally visible location]
2. Event pointer - [Inside the class that triggers the event]
3. Event method - [Inside the class that triggers the event]
4. (OnEvent) method wrapper - [Inside the class that triggers the event]
5. Code that wires the event - [Inside the form???]

Is this in the ball park? Can 3&4 be located in a class outside the one that triggers the event?
Thanks

Comment: If you want an event to trigger in another class, then the other class can subscribe to that event. I created a project recently that was based on a hierarchy 3 or 4 levels deep. Each parent and child class inherited an "IEventBubbler" which included an `ChildEventTrigger` method and an `BubbleParent` property. Events fired at any level would bubble up the hierarchy and any parent could perform actions based on an event at a lower level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you have class that detects value and you want to update a text box
>   in a form

Then declare/define the event in the class where it detects value and raise the event from that same class passing the parameter when it detected the value.

In form (where you wanted to update the text box) hook up with that event (register the event) and do update the text box in handler method.

Comment: Great info! Can the event method/wrapper be in a different class outside the one that detects the event. I'm thinking of the possibility of reusing code between different classes that may trigger the same event...if that makes sense

Comment: Yes, it can and in such case you will have to make that handler as `public` method. More suitably a `public static` method probably in a helper class.

Comment: Thanks- The web has a lot of event info and examples it is hard to determine the right way to implement events. This has been a lot of help.